# Yago2s dump to N-Triples conversion

Tags: semantic-web, dbpedia

I downloaded YAGO 2.5.3 dump of Turtle format from https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/archive/. I was trying to use the extraction framework https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/blob/dump/scripts/src/main/bash/process-yago.txt to convert the dump into N-Triples format but getting the following error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.155 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-05T17:04:57-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.dbpedia.extraction:core:jar:4.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.sweble.wikitext:swc-engine:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.sweble.wikitext:swc-engine:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.sweble.wikitext:swc-engine:pom:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT from/to osr-public-releases (http://mojo.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/nexus/content/repositories/public-releases): Access denied to: http://mojo.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/nexus/content/repositories/public-releases/org/sweble/wikitext/swc-engine/1.1.1-SNAPSHOT/swc-engine-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :core
```

Is there any alternative way available to convert the Yago dump into N-Triples.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert between different RDF serializations with the [Raptor RDF syntax parsing and serializing utility](http://librdf.org/raptor/).

Usage:

```
rapper -i turtle -o ntriples /path/to/my/file.ttl > /path/to/output.nt
```